What exactly does the Greek word for ‘meet’ (ἀπάντησιν) used by Paul in 1 Thessalonians 4:17 mean?
First off, I will admit that I have less-than-elementary understanding of Greek, so please correct me where I may be wrong. Additionally, a similar question is asked here, but from what I've read, there is no discussion as it relates to this particular Greek term, so I will pose the question.
In 1 Thessalonians 4:17 (KJV), the Apostle Paul writes:

“Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord.”

From my understanding, the Greek word translated as “to meet" here (ἀπάντησιν from ἀπάντησις) holds a distinct definition and conveys a specific image. It appears to be used to describe an event in which a prominent figure is approaching, and a group from the destination goes out to meet the figure, subsequently escorting or ushering them back to the original location (the place where the meeting party initially came from). It seems to suggest a "round trip", rather than a "one-way ticket" meeting, so to speak.
With all of this, I have a few related questions

Does this term ever represent a type of meeting unlike what I've described here? Biblical and extra-biblical references would be helpful.
If/when it does imply a round trip sort of meeting, are there contextual indicators to determine whether the return portion happens immediately, or could it be delayed by a significant interval?

Admittedly, I struggle to verbally explain precisely what I mean when describing the term, so this visual representation may help.

I’d appreciate any insights or clarification on this term and its application in this passage. Thank you, and God bless.

Aren't you thinking about the word parousia (παρουσία), that can be found in the verse 15?
"For this we declare to you by a word from the Lord, that we who are alive, who are left until the COMING of the Lord, will not precede those who have fallen asleep."

"In the ancient world the term parousia (“coming”) referred to a royal visitation. Any time a high-ranking dignitary, even Caesar himself, came for a visit everyone would gather outside and throw a big party and welcome him into their town."

@ארקדיוס While this is also an important term in the passage that emphasizes something unique, no I'm referring to the word Paul uses for "meet" in "to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord." From my understanding, this meeting (perhaps common in the event of a parousia) is quite technical in nature.

The ignorant me only knew about the meaning of parousia. That is why I thought you may be applying the cultural context of parousia to apantesis. The picture you used illustrates both. I had to do my research to understand what you meant. Yes, both those words are very technical in the context of the Roman culture.

I have to admit, I needed to do some extra research to answer your question. But, what a fruitful research it was. It definitely opened a new door of understanding for me.
Right off the bat, we have to establish, that the cultural context of the word in the NT was strictly Roman. The basic definition of apantesis doesn't help, and should not be applied here. Just like the examples from the texts that predate the apostolic times.

"In the Roman Empire during Late Antiquity, the adventus (Ancient
Greek: ἀπάντησις, romanized: apántēsis, lit. 'escort') was a ceremony
held to celebrate the arrival (Latin: adventus) at a city of a Roman
emperor or other dignitaries. The imperial adventus was the period's
"ceremonial par excellence", celebrating both the emperor's arrival
and the blessing of the imperial presence itself on the city's
security. The term is also used to refer to artistic depictions
(usually in relief sculpture, including coins) of such ceremonies.
The city would be decorated for the occasion, a public procession
would come out of the city to meet and welcome the honorand on the
road, and after ritually escorting them into town, a panegyric would
be delivered in their honour, followed by a festival and games. Its
'opposite' was the profectio. Besides the emperors, governors of the
Roman provinces and bishops could be received by an adventus.
For an emperor, especially one having newly acceded or usurped power,
celebrating an adventus confirmed the legitimacy of the ruler,
demonstrating the consent (Latin: consensus) of the governed city's
people, and the events were reproduced and symbolized in imperial
iconography and art. From the time of Constantine the Great's
(r. 306–337) arrival in Rome after defeating his rival Augustus
Maxentius (r. 306–312) at the Battle of the Milvian Bridge, the
adventus ceremonies of the emperors took on characteristics of the
Roman triumph and were associated with the triumphal entry into
Jerusalem by Jesus of Nazareth described in the gospels of the New
Testament. Christian relics were sometimes also honoured with an
adventus ceremony during a translation to a city.
The two major elements of the adventus were the rituals of occursus
and propompe. The occursus (Ancient Greek: συνάντησις, romanized:
synántēsis, lit. 'meeting' or Ancient Greek: ὑπάντησις, romanized:
hypántēsis, lit. 'coming to meet') consisted of the ritual procession
to meet the approaching honorand on the road; the size, composition,
and distance from the city of the welcoming party was determined by
the guest's rank and status. Then, the propompe was the festive escort
of the honorand into the city. The delivery of panegyric in honour of
the occasion and in praise of the arrival was an enduring fixture, as
were acclamations, hymns, poetry, music, lights, decorations and
incense. Religious shrines would be visited en route, and afterwards a
banquet was probably held."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventus_(ceremony)
All three texts where apantesis in used gain more substance when we know the cultural meaning behind the term.

6 “At midnight the cry rang out: ‘Here’s the bridegroom! Come out to
meet him!’ 7 “Then all the virgins woke up and trimmed their lamps. 8
The foolish ones said to the wise, ‘Give us some of your oil; our
lamps are going out.’ 9 “ ‘No,’ they replied, ‘there may not be enough
for both us and you. Instead, go to those who sell oil and buy some
for yourselves.’ 10 “But while they were on their way to buy the oil,
the bridegroom arrived. The virgins who were ready went in with him to
the wedding banquet. And the door was shut. (Matthew 25)
15 According to the Lord’s word, we tell you that we who are still
alive, who are left until the coming of the Lord, will certainly not
precede those who have fallen asleep. 16 For the Lord himself will
come down from heaven, with a loud command, with the voice of the
archangel and with the trumpet call of God, and the dead in Christ
will rise first. 17 After that, we who are still alive and are left
will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in
the air. And so we will be with the Lord forever. (1 Thessalonians 4 )

In both cases, the Christ returning as the king of creation (parousia) is met with the escort of the believers (apantesis). Interestingly, the Roman context is mixed with the Jewish ones of God as the bridegroom of Israel and the eschatological banquet. Yes, it is quite complex.

14 There we found some brothers and sisters who invited us to spend a
week with them. And so we came to Rome. 15 The brothers and sisters
there had heard that we were coming, and they traveled as far as the
Forum of Appius and the Three Taverns to meet us. At the sight of
these people Paul thanked God and was encouraged. 16 When we got to
Rome, Paul was allowed to live by himself, with a soldier to guard
him. (Acts 28)

That was not an ordinary meeting. As Paul approached the city, two different groups of brothers and sisters, greeted him at great distances from the city. It was a royal welcome. People travelled 40–50 kilometres to greet Paul and to escort him to Rome.

The Forum Appii (or Appii Forum) is an ancient post station on the Via
Appia, 63.5 km (39.5 imperial miles; 43 Roman miles) southeast of
Rome, founded, no doubt, by the original constructor of the road.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forum_Appii

Tre Taverne  was a place on the ancient Appian Way, about 50 km (31
miles) from Rome, designed for the reception of travellers, as the
name indicates.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tre_Taverne

The noun ἀπάντησις simply "meeting" or "encounter" and occurs just three times in the NT (one or two more are disputed):

Matt 25:6 - At midnight the cry rang out: ‘Here is the bridegroom! Come out to meet him!’
Acts 28:15 - The brothers there had heard about us and traveled as far as the Forum of Appius and the Three Taverns to meet us. When Paul saw them, he was encouraged and gave thanks to God.
1 Thess 4:17 - After that, we who are alive and remain will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And so we will always be with the Lord.

Note that in all these occasions, the word is preceded by εἰς (= "to"); ie, all occur in the phrase "to meet".
In the LXX the word occurs frequently such as Judg 4:18, 11:31, 34, 14:5, 15:4, 19:3, 20:25, 31, 1 Sam 4:1, 9:14, 13:10, 15, 15:12, 25:32, 34, 30:21, 2 Sam 6:20, 19:25, 1 Chr 12:17, 14:8, 19:5, 2 Chr 12:11, 15:2, 19:2, 20:17, 28:9, Jer 27:3, 41:6, 51:31, etc.  Again, always preceded by εἰς giving the phrase "to meet".
The word is a rather ordinary word. Here is an extract from Strong's lexicon on this word:

Meaning: the act of meeting, to meet (a phrase seemingly almost technical for the reception of a newly arrived official).
Word Origin: Derived from the Greek verb ἀπαντάω (apantaō), meaning "to meet" or "to encounter."
Corresponding Greek / Hebrew Entries: While there is no direct Hebrew equivalent for "apantésis," the concept of meeting or
encountering can be found in Hebrew words like קָרָא (qara) and
פָּגַשׁ (pagash), which also convey the idea of coming together or
meeting.
Usage: The term "apantésis" refers to a meeting or encounter, often used in the context of a formal or significant meeting. In the
New Testament, it is used to describe the act of going out to meet
someone, often with the implication of a welcoming or celebratory
nature.
Cultural and Historical Background: In ancient Greek culture, "apantésis" was often used to describe the custom of citizens going
out to meet a visiting dignitary or important person as a sign of
respect and honor. This practice was common in both civic and
religious contexts, where the act of meeting was not just a physical
encounter but also a ceremonial gesture of welcome and recognition.

However, note that the word is often used of both friendly and unfriendly encounters.  (See above list from the LXX.)

1.) Curious about the discrepancy between suggesting an ordinary meeting vs the Strong’s lexicon suggesting otherwise. 2.) Excluding 1 Thessalonians for now, don’t the other verses imply a meeting with the intent of accompanying or escorting someone? In Matthew 25:6, the meeting involves ushering in the bridegroom, consistent with a formal wedding event, and in Acts 28:15, the brothers’ journey suggests more than a casual meeting—it seems they intended to welcome and accompany Paul to his destination (Rome in this case).

@JacobMcDougle - quite true.  However, the meaning includes more than just this idea such as those in the LXX and listed above.

It seems a bit strange that it would be so frequently used when translating the Hebrew to Greek, but so infrequently used in the NT itself, especially given what the Strong's lexicon offers regarding the term. Still curious for this discrepancy.

@JacobMcDougle - do not make the mistake of forcing a meaning on a word that was not intended.  Look at all the instances - the meaning "meeting" is enough to translate them all - some rather casual and some auspicious.  What is difficult about that?

the suggestion in the lexicon that it is not simply any meeting, but a specific, technical term - that's the discrepancy I find strange...

@JacobMcDougle - there is no discrepancy - look at what the lexicon is saying - it includes BOTH meanings!!

It first states it is a technical term, then states there is no hebrew equivalent, describes how it is used (IN A VERY TECHNICAL WAY), and then gives the cultural background... it seems to almost exclusively imply more than just a mere meeting.....................
